# wp_insert_post custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, wp-insert-post

I have a custom post type **`books`** and a custom taxonomy **`books-categories`**. `wp_insert_post()` and it works. How  can i add a second taxonomy called **`location`**? This code doeasn't save my custom taxonomy called **`location`**.
Can anyone help me please?

```
<?php
if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) &&  $_POST['action'] == "new_post") {

    // Do some minor form validation to make sure there is content
    if (isset ($_POST['title'])) {
        $title =  $_POST['title'];
    } else {
        echo 'Please enter a  title';
    }
    if (isset ($_POST['description'])) {
        $description = $_POST['description'];
    } else {
        echo 'Please enter the content';
    }
    $tags = $_POST['post_tags'];

    // Add the content of the form to $post as an array
    $new_post = array(
        'post_title'    => $title,
        'post_content'  => $description,
        'post_category' => array($_POST['cat']),  // Usable for custom taxonomies too
        'tags_input'    => array($tags),
        'post_status'   => 'draft',           // Choose: publish, preview, future, draft, etc.
        'post_type' => 'books'  //'post',page' or use a custom post type if you want to
    );
    //save the new post
    $pid = wp_insert_post($new_post); 
    //insert taxonomies
    wp_set_post_terms( $pid, $_POST['cat'], 'books-categories', false );
    wp_set_post_terms( $pid, $_POST['location'], 'location', false );
}

?>  

<!-- New Post Form -->
<div id="postbox">
<form id="new_post" name="new_post" method="post" action="">

<!-- post name -->
<p><label for="title">Title</label><br />
<input type="text" id="title" value="" tabindex="1" size="20" name="title" />
</p>

<!-- post Category -->
<p><label for="Category">Category:</label><br />
<p><?php wp_dropdown_categories( 'show_option_none=Category&tab_index=4&taxonomy=books-categories' ); ?></p>

<!-- post Location -->
<p><label for="Location">Location:</label><br />
<p><?php wp_dropdown_categories( 'show_option_none=Category&tab_index=4&taxonomy=location' ); ?></p>

<!-- post Content -->
<p><label for="description">Content</label><br />
<textarea id="description" tabindex="3" name="description" cols="50" rows="6"></textarea>
</p>

<!-- post tags -->
<p><label for="post_tags">Tags:</label>
<input type="text" value="" tabindex="5" size="16" name="post_tags" id="post_tags" /></p>
<p align="right"><input type="submit" value="Publish" tabindex="6" id="submit" name="submit" /></p>

<input type="hidden" name="action" value="new_post" />
<?php wp_nonce_field( 'new-post' ); ?>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**wp_set_post_terms() function will only work on the native post type**.

For a taxonomy on a custom post type use [wp_set_object_terms()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms).

Change your code to:

```
wp_set_object_terms( $pid, $_POST['cat'], 'books-categories', false );
wp_set_object_terms( $pid, $_POST['location'], 'location', false );
```

Comment: I did that but location didn't  work again,and on books-categories was created another category called "101".

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have two inputs both sending data with `name` of `cat`.

You need to change the second instance of:

```
wp_dropdown_categories( 'show_option_none=Category&tab_index=4&taxonomy=location' )
```

to:

```
wp_dropdown_categories( 'show_option_none=Category&tab_index=4&taxonomy=location&name=location,' )
```

And then change this:
        `wp_set_post_terms( $pid, $_POST['cat'], 'location', false );`

to:
    `wp_set_post_terms( $pid, $_POST['location'], 'location', false );`

Comment: Still, location taxonomy doesn't work... :/

Comment: Does `location` appear in the admin panel, in the sub menu underneath the `Books` menu item in the admin menu?

Comment: Yes,it appears like books categories...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
//hook into the init action and call create_book_taxonomies when it fires
 add_action( 'init', 'create_topics_hierarchical_taxonomy', 0 );

 //create a custom taxonomy name it topics for your posts

 function create_topics_hierarchical_taxonomy() {

    // Add new taxonomy, make it hierarchical like categories
    //first do the translations part for GUI

   $labels = array(
     'name' => _x( 'Topics', 'taxonomy general name' ),
     'singular_name' => _x( 'Topic', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
     'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Topics' ),
     'all_items' => __( 'All Topics' ),
     'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Topic' ),
     'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Topic:' ),
     'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Topic' ), 
     'update_item' => __( 'Update Topic' ),
     'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Topic' ),
     'new_item_name' => __( 'New Topic Name' ),
     'menu_name' => __( 'Topics' ),
  );    

 // Now register the taxonomy

 register_taxonomy('topics',array('post'), array(
  'hierarchical' => true,
  'labels' => $labels,
  'show_ui' => true,
  'show_admin_column' => true,
  'query_var' => true,
  'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'topic' ),
 ));

}
```

Comment: No,unfortunately this doesn't work...

Comment: I wonder if the problem is here,maybe i should do the same thing for taxonomy location...                                                                                 $new_post = array(
        'post_category' => array($_POST['cat'])

Comment: how to set this code and where to set

Comment: In array i set ['cat'] as post category, maybe i must set ['location'] also

Answer (score 0):

`wp_set_object_term` is the function you need. Please see this page,

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms

```
wp_set_object_terms( $pid, array($_POST['cat']), 'books-categories' );
wp_set_object_terms( $pid, array($_POST['location']), 'location' );
```

Hope this one helps :)