# wp_insert_post custom type and custom taxonomies

Tags: wp-insert-post

I have a custom post type **`books`** and 3 custom taxonomies attached to **`books`**. The custom taxonomies are: **`books-categories`** , **`location`** , **`services_c`**. How should i edit my form to get my taxonomies work;
I'm trying to solve this for 3 days and but i can't. Can anyone help me please?

```
<?php
if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) &&  $_POST['action'] == "new_post") {

    // Do some minor form validation to make sure there is content
    if (isset ($_POST['title'])) {
        $title =  $_POST['title'];
    } else {
        echo 'Please enter a  title';
    }
    if (isset ($_POST['description'])) {
        $description = $_POST['description'];
    } else {
        echo 'Please enter the content';
    }
    $tags = $_POST['post_tags'];

    // Add the content of the form to $post as an array
    $new_post = array(
        'post_title'    => $title,
        'post_content'  => $description,
        'tags_input'    => array($tags),
        'post_status'   => 'draft',           // Choose: publish, preview, future, draft, etc.
        'post_type' => 'books'  //'post',page' or use a custom post type if you want to
    );
    //save the new post
    $pid = wp_insert_post($new_post); 

}

?>  

<!-- New Post Form -->
<div id="postbox">
<form id="new_post" name="new_post" method="post" action="">

<!-- post name -->
<p><label for="title">Title</label><br />
<input type="text" id="title" value="" tabindex="1" size="20" name="title" />
</p>

<!-- post Category -->
<p><label for="Category">Category:</label><br />
<p><?php wp_dropdown_categories( 'show_option_none=Category&tab_index=4&taxonomy=books-categories' ); ?></p>

<!-- post Location -->
<p><label for="Location">Location:</label><br />
<p><?php wp_dropdown_categories( 'show_option_none=Category&tab_index=4&taxonomy=location' ); ?></p>

<!-- post Services -->
<p><label for="Services">Services:</label><br />
<p><?php wp_dropdown_categories( 'show_option_none=Category&tab_index=4&taxonomy=services_c' ); ?></p>

<!-- post Content -->
<p><label for="description">Content</label><br />
<textarea id="description" tabindex="3" name="description" cols="50" rows="6"></textarea>
</p>

<!-- post tags -->
<p><label for="post_tags">Tags:</label>
<input type="text" value="" tabindex="5" size="16" name="post_tags" id="post_tags" /></p>
<p align="right"><input type="submit" value="Publish" tabindex="6" id="submit" name="submit" /></p>

<input type="hidden" name="action" value="new_post" />
<?php wp_nonce_field( 'new-post' ); ?>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a duplicate, of your own question - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/247409/wp-insert-post-custom-taxonomy/

Comment: You need to read my answer again, and try what I posted, as I can see from the code in your new question that you missed a couple bits. when calling `wp_dropdown_categories` you need to add a parameter which will give the form element a different name (at the moment all those dropdowns have the same `name`).

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is a little flawed - you run `isset` checks on fields like `title` and `description`, but don't actually halt the post insertion if they're not set.

You also *don't* check the `post_tags` index, which will never exist because `wp_dropdown_categories` will use the field name `cat` unless you set it to something else.

Not to mention that `tags_input` is specifically for the taxonomy `post_tag`, so even if everything else was working, the terms would never be properly assigned.

Let's refactor and use the [PHP filter AP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php)I while we're at it:

```
<?php

if ( 'POST' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'action' ) === 'new_post' ) {
    $errors      = [];
    $title       = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'title',       FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
    $description = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'description', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );

    if ( ! $title ) {
        $errors[] = 'Please enter a title';
    }

    if ( ! $description ) {
        $errors[] = 'Please enter a description';
    }

    if ( ! $errors ) {
        $new_post_id = wp_insert_post([
            'post_title'   => $title,
            'post_content' => $description,
            'post_status'  => 'draft',
            'post_type'    => 'books',
        ]);

        if ( ! $new_post_id ) {
            $errors[] = 'Oops, something went wrong';
        } else {
            /**
             * Loop over taxonomies and attempt to set post terms.
             */
            foreach ([
                'books-categories',
                'location',
                'services_c',
            ] as $post_taxonomy ) {

                // Field name is the format "{taxonomy}_term_id"
                if ( $term_id = ( int ) filter_input( INPUT_POST, "{$post_taxonomy}_term_id" ) ) {
                    wp_set_object_terms( $new_post_id, $term_id, $post_taxonomy );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    foreach ( $errors as $error ) {
        echo "$error<br />";
    }
}
```

Now we just need to set the right input `name` for each taxonomy dropdown - I've used the format `{taxonomy}_term_id` so as not to confuse WordPress (if you used *just* the taxonomy name as the input, it will likely clash with the `query_var` for said taxonomy).

```
wp_dropdown_categories( 'name=books-categories_term_id&show_option_none=Category&tab_index=4&taxonomy=books-categories' );
```

Do the same for the others and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

```
  add_filter('single_template', 'my_single_template');
    function my_single_template() {
        global $post;
        $this_plugin_dir = WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/' . str_replace(basename(__FILE__), "", plugin_basename(__FILE__));
        //echo $post->post_type; exit;
        /* Checks for single template by post type */
        if ($post->post_type == 'articles') {
            if (file_exists($this_plugin_dir . '/templates/single-articles.php')) {
                return $this_plugin_dir . '/templates/single-articles.php';
            }
        }
        return $single;
    }
```